# Fastest time to Moon for Starship

Tags: the-moon, spacex-starship

What is the fastest time to the Moon possible with Starship in the near future, assuming there is orbital refueling?
Is sustained acceleration and then deceleration possible at say 0.25G, to reduce this time?

Comment: Why is 24 hours the time limit for commerce?  You realize that trading across both the Atlantic and Pacific was a huge deal for centuries before even the steam engine was invented, and everyone did it with just wind power?  And for a good century, rail travel across the US was a matter of weeks, not hours or days.  What makes you put an arbitrary time limit here? What's wrong with a three to five day travel time to the moon?

Comment: Look, if I can't Amazon Prime toilet paper to the moonbase overnight if I run low, I'm not going.

Comment: Even if it's technically feasible to deliver cargo to/from the moon in under 24 hours, it will inevitably mean more fuel burned for a smaller payload than taking the long way. It's not likely to be economically feasible.

Comment: I think "making lunar commerce possible" is detracting from your otherwise good question. Eventually there will be valid reasons to want to speed up the trip in some cases when possible, even if there is an additional fuel cost, just like there is in car and plane travel. There will likely be cases where Starship is flying with a lower payload which would make a faster trip time possible.  Maximum speed would be used in less common situations such as a medical evacuation, or sending a critical piece of life support hardware to restore redundancy after say a double failure.

Comment: I agree with @StevePemberton.  If you remove the phrase "and maybe make some sort of Lunar Commerce possible", this would be a much better question.

Comment: @RussellBorogove God forbid you have to walk to the Space Bodega.

Comment: Agreed. Edited the question.

Comment: Not sure I can answer this @safe_malloc, as .25g of acceleration would be impossible to keep up for 24 hours...
(With raptor engines)

Comment: Ok. What is the fastest time to the Moon possible with currently known information about starship?

Comment: Tangentially related to what someone said, but I think you overestimate how long conventional chemical rocket engines burn. Saturn V only burned for 18 minutes to get to the moon, and I doubt any reasonable chemical rocket will have *that* much longer of a burn. There are other engine types that give higher efficiency and longer burn times, but they’re not currently relevant to Starship. You generally either get (1) high thrust low burn time or (2) low thrust high burn time. Sustained .25g acceleration all the way to the moon would be a game changer